# Must I reformat my hard drive to reclaim space from unused 2nd partition?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, unix, unibody

I wanted to see if I could also have Ubuntu on my Macbook alongside the usual OSX. Now, a year later, I want to remove the Ubuntu and the space associated with it on the hard drive. That is, my hd is partitioned into two separate spaces.

My question is, if I want back the space that Ubuntu took, must I reformat and delete everything on my Mac?

Answer (score 1):

You won't need that, you can delete your Ubuntu partition and expand the current OSX one.

Using Disk Utility :

- Choose your hard drive
- Under the Partition tab
- Delete your ubuntu partition and expand the OS partition.

Comment: Are you sure? I think I tried that and didnt work. Ill try again now.

Comment: It usually works.  But if Disk Utility is not allowing it in your case, then you probably *do* have to reformat.

Comment: Or: you can boot a live Ubuntu CD/USB stick, and use GParted to delete the Ubuntu partition. Then reboot back in OS X and expand the OS X partition with Disk Utility.